# Accessing textview on viewcontroller.xib from another class

Tags: objective-c

I have a textview on my `viewcontroller.xib` and I have a method to modify the text. I want to access that textview method on `viewcontroller.m` from a created object. I have a class called person that has in the init method to call the viewcontroller's method to update the text. Basically I want the textview to say "Person Created".

Here is the code I use inside my `-init` method of the person class which does not work:

```
ViewController * Viewscreen = (ViewController *) [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
[Viewscreen UpdateScreenText:@"Person Created!"];
```

Answer (score 0):

`ViewController * Viewscreen = (ViewController *) [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];`

This looks very strange to me, is your App Delegate really named `ViewController`? Are you trying to access a property declared in your App Delegate called `Viewscreen`?

If so then you would want to use the following to get a reference to it

`ViewController * Viewscreen = [(ViewController *) [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] Viewscreen];`

Please clarify some more and we may be able to better assist.

Comment: OK it's a view based application. There is no goal in mind for it I'm just trying to learn some new things. What I'm trying to do is create an object of a class, and have that object report to a textview on my viewcontroller.xib that it was created.

What I have is a textview on the xib of viewcontroller, 

A method on viewcontroller implementation that updates the text of it, and 

I have a person class and in the init of the person class I want it to declare it was created to my viewcontroller.xib textview